# having problems with installing the digimend kernel driver

Tags: drivers, software-installation, kernel, dpkg, graphics-tablet

I use a H610 Pro (Huion) and I'm completely new to linux, also I am on Ubuntu

I try-

```
$ sudo apt install digimend-kernel-9.deb
E: unable to locate package digimend-kernel-drivers-9.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'digimend-kernel-drivers-9.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'digimend-kernel-drivers-9.deb'
```

I've also tried directing it to its exact directory, but it gives me-

```
E: Unsupported file /home/desktop/digimend-kernel-drivers-9.deb given on commandline
```

I've also tried to install it from the source, but it gives me the exact same error from before but replace .deb with .tar.gz with both things I said previously.

Comment: `/home/desktop/...` most likely would lead to a wrong and non-existing directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You install downloaded `deb` packages by:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file
```

Comment: If dependencies exist, you have to install them with `sudo apt install -f` manually after installation of each deb-package.

Comment: That's true. Let's see what OP gets.

Comment: What exactly does /path/to/file mean? When I use that command exactly, replace it with digimend-kernel-driver-9.deb, or combine the two the terminal returns with no such file or directory found

Comment: This means path to the place where the file is. Where is the file? Like `~/Desktop/digimend-kernel-drivers-9.deb`

Comment: @Pilot6 Tried `sudo dpkg -i /home/desktop/digimend-kernel-drivers-9.deb` and it still returned with no such file or directory. I swear it is stored in the file /home/desktop...

Comment: This is obviously a wrong path. Is it on your desktop? Then the correct path is `~/Desktop/digimend-kernel-drivers-9.deb`. There is no `/home/desktop` directory unless your user is called `desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the directory with deb-files and then add `./` before deb-package filename, as follows:

```
sudo apt install ./digimend-kernel-9.deb
sudo apt install ./digimend-kernel-drivers-9.deb
```

or use full file-paths:

```
sudo apt install /path/to/file/digimend-kernel-9.deb
sudo apt install /path/to/file/digimend-kernel-drivers-9.deb
```

to install them with dependencies.

Comment: This obviously won't work if you are not in the right driectory. What do you think `./` means?